# SOLUÇÃO para erro JAVA 8 - windows 8

Tags: java-8

Estou com um problema para rodar um programa que requer o JAVA. Antes ele rodava com o JAVA 7 e agora tá pedindo o JAVA 8. Fiz o que foi pedido, no entanto, o apareceu o seguintes erro:

Erro de aplicação

> Class Not Found Exception
>
> oracle.forms.engine.Main

Estou utilizando o windows 8

Comment: Poderia postar o seu código?

Answer (score 1):

Isso me parece erro de classpath.

experimente passar o classpath no momento em que você executa o comando java